# How to find the shortest path that visits all selected nodes in a tree?

Tags: java, c#, algorithm

I know there are many similar path-finding questions around and I have a brief idea of Dijkstra's algorithm. But I am stuck at this problem I have got here and I believe this is not so straight forward. Let me explain how it is first:

I have a tree which represents an explored path graph. If I write the path node class in Java/C# syntax, it will be like the following. (Note: there are cost to move to another node)

```
class Path {
    Path parent;
    Path north;
    int costToNorth;
    Path east;
    int costToEast;
    Path south;
    int costToSouth;
    Path west;
    int costToWest;
}
```

Imagine a tree like this:

```
[root] Node A
    [north] Node B
        [north] Node F
        [east]  Node G
            [north]  Node H
    [east]  Node C
        [east]  Node I
            [north] Node N
            [east]  Node O
        [south] Node J
    [south] Node D
        [south] Node K
            [east]  Node P
            [south] Node Q
    [west]  Node E
        [south] Node L
        [west]  Node M
```

If I have a set of nodes that I must visit, e.g. **Node B, D, H, J, M, O, P**
and I am not necessarily starting at root A, let's say I am at Node E from the beginning, and I want to finish at certain Node, let's say Node F.

**how can I find a shortest continuous path, starting from Node E, that allows me to visit all the selected nodes listed above in any order, and finish the path at Node F?**

By shortest, I mean the least sum of costs when moving between nodes.

At first I thought this means applying Dijkstra's algorithm to every node-to-node combination, but when I tried to code it, I feel I am not going in the right direction.

I am looking for codes or explained algorithm for reference.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @EJoshuaS he did already say he tried Dijkstra's. That seems like enough to me. I think the poster is mostly just looking for an Algorithm name to research and they can probably handle it from there.

Comment: @Peter Duniho I think the traveling salesman on trees is not NP-complete, because I think the minimal tour will always tour all of the nodes in a subtree before leaving it, and I think this means you can solve it by dynamic programming on trees. This problem asks for a path between two named nodes, which makes the dynamic programming solution not quite as elegant. I have provided a rather ad-hoc answer which I believe finds an optimal solution, although I have not provided a proof of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that on a tree there is only one sensible path from A to B. Go up from A to the lowest common ancestor of A and B and then go down from there to B. More generally, if you have a tree with a collection of nodes you care about, and a subtree which does not contain any of these nodes, you know that none of the best paths among the nodes you care about will go via that subtree.

I would start off by deleting all of the leaves in the tree you don't have to visit, and then any new leaves that this creates that you don't have to visit, and so on, until you have a tree whose leaves are only the nodes you have to visit. If this has a root with only one child, delete that root, and so on, until you you have a root with at least two children.

Now start off with a path from E up to the root and from there down to F. If this visits all of the other nodes you are done. Otherwise there is at least one subtree whose root is on that path that contains other nodes that you have to visit. Edit into the path a tour that leaves the path to do a depth first tour of the subtree and then returns back up to the path. Continue until you have accounted for all of the nodes not visited.

Comment: Thank you. That's a very sensible answer. Much more efficient than using the traveling salesman